# R raster package problem with extract() function

Tags: raster, r

I'm trying to extract pixel value using the `extract()` function from `raster` package in R and get the following error, bellow in my code bellow a well, where: `df$PixelNumber` is the "cell number value". The error :

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"character",
>   "numeric"’

the code I'm using:

```
vec=as.vector(as.numeric(as.matrix(df$PixelNumber)));
rast = file.choose();
VlaueSlope=extract(x= rast, vec)
```

What could I be doing wrong in the `extract()` code that cannot get the pixel value in the variable `VlaueSlope`.

Comment: Could you try `vec = as.numeric(as.matrix(df$PixelNumber)))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error:

```
    Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : 
     unable to find an inherited method for
     function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"character", "numeric"’
```

is saying you are calling `extract` with a "character" argument and a "numeric" argument. How are you calling it? Let's see...

```
VlaueSlope=extract(x= rast, vec)
```

so what is `rast`? Let's see:

```
rast = file.choose();
```

`rast` is the **file name** it is **NOT** the raster data. You need to read in the raster using something like:

```
rasterpath = file.choose()
rast = raster(rasterpath)
```

and then you can extract the pixel values if everything else is correct.

In summary: try and understand error messages, read the documentation for functions, and check your arguments match the ones documented.

Comment: Yes, indeed I had has this mistake now works!!! Thanks!! how can In get the rather of only all (the cell original cell values of the raster) but only where  the are points? thanks